# Redirect htaccess rule

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I wish to redirect a website link onto another.

my htaccess rule up to now is

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteRule ^/the-terminal/demo/ http://example.com/wordpress/project-overview/ [R,L]
```

I wish to redirect the link `http://example.com/wordpress/the-terminal/demo` to `http://example.com/wordpress/project-overview`

Kindly provide me a solution. You will be a lifesaver.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `/the-terminal/demo` is a Wordpress page, the following applies:

The previous rewrite rule is being matched, so the second rule is skipped:

```
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
```

The `[L]` flag tells Apache to stop the rewrite process immediately and ignore any further rules.

To solve this, move your rule immediately after `RewriteBase`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule the-terminal/demo http://example.com/wordpress/project-overview/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```